# How to get params in parent route component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I'm building an app with React, React-Router (v5) and Redux and wonder how to access the params of the current URL in a parent route.

That's my entry, the `router.js`:

```
<Wrapper>
  <Route exact path="/login" render={(props) => (
    <LoginPage {...props} entryPath={this.entryPath} />
  )} />

  <Route exact path="/" component={UserIsAuthenticated(HomePage)} />
  <Route exact path="/about" component={UserIsAuthenticated(AboutPage)} />
  <Route path="/projects" component={UserIsAuthenticated(ProjectsPage)} />
</Wrapper>
```

And that's my `ProjectsPage` component:

```
class ProjectsPage extends PureComponent {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchProjectsRequest()
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props.active)

    if (this.props.loading) {
      return <Loading />
    } else {
      return (
        <Wrapper>
          <Sidebar>
            <ProjectList projects={this.props.projects} />
          </Sidebar>
          <Content>
            <Route exact path="/projects" component={ProjectsDashboard} />

            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/projects/new" component={ProjectNew} />
              <Route exact path="/projects/:id/edit" component={ProjectEdit} />
              <Route exact path="/projects/:id" component={ProjectPage} />
            </Switch>
          </Content>
        </Wrapper>
      )
    }
  }
}

const enhance = connect(
  (state, props) => ({
    active: props.match,
    loading: projectSelectors.loading(state),
    projects: projectSelectors.projects(state)
  }),
  {
    fetchProjectsRequest
  }
)

export default withRouter(enhance(ProjectsPage))
```

The problem is, that the `console.log` output in my `render` method is `{"path":"/projects","url":"/projects","isExact":false,"params":{}}` although the URL is `http://localhost:3000/projects/14`.

I want to add an `ID` prop to my `ProjectList` to highlight the currently selected project.

I could save the ID of the project in a store inside my `ProjectPage` component, but I think this would be a bit confusing, especially because the URL has the information actually – so why should I write something in the store?

Another (bad?) approach would be to parse the location object the get the ID by myself, but I think there is a `react-router`/`react-router-redux` way to get the params at this point that I've overlooked.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

@Kyle explained issue very well from technical perspective.
I will just focus on solution to that problem.

You can use `matchPath` to get `id` of selected project.

**matchPath** - https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/matchPath

> This lets you use the same matching code that  uses except
>   outside of the normal render cycle, like gathering up data
>   dependencies before rendering on the server.

Usage in this case is very straight forward.

## 1 Use `matchPath`

```
// history is one of the props passed by react-router to component
// @link https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history

const match = matchPath(history.location.pathname, {
  // You can share this string as a constant if you want
  path: "/articles/:id"
});

let articleId;

// match can be null
if (match && match.params.id) {
  articleId = match.params.id;
}
```

## 2 Use `articleId` in render

```
{articleId && (
  <h1>You selected article with id: {articleId}</h1>
)}
```

I build a simple demo which you can use to implement the same functionality in your project.

**Demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/pQo6YMZop

I think that this solution is quite elegant because we use official `react-router` API which is also used for path matching in router. We also don't use `window.location` here so testing / mocking will be easy if you export also raw component.

Comment: This is great! That's what I've looked for :-) At the moment I'm using `router-parser`, but using a method from the `react-router` package makes absolute sense. In fact, I'm already using constants for the route :-)

Answer (score 2):

**TLDR**

React router `match.params` will be an empty object if your `<Route />` `path` property doesn't include `:params`.

*Solve this use case*: You could use `let id = window.location.pathname.split("/").pop();` in your parent route's component to get the id.

**Detailed reason why not**

If the `path` prop supplied to a `<Route />` doesn't have any params, such as `/:id`, react router isn't going to doing the parsing for you. If you look in `matchPath.js` at line #56 you can start to see how the `match` prop is constructed.

```
return {
  path: path, // the path pattern used to match
  url: path === '/' && url === '' ? '/' : url, // the matched portion of the URL
  isExact: isExact, // whether or not we matched exactly
  params: keys.reduce(function (memo, key, index) {
      memo[key.name] = values[index];
      return memo;
  }, {})
};
```

Then we can look at line #43 you can see that `keys` comes from `_compilePath.keys`. We can then look at the `compilePath` function and see that it uses `pathToRegexp()`, which will use `stringToRegexp()`, which will use `tokensToRegExp()` which will then mutate `keys` on line #355 with `keys.push(token)`. With a `<Route />` that has no params value in its `path` prop, the `parse()` function used in `stringToRegexp()` will not return any tokens and line #355 won't even be reached because the only tokens array will not contain any token objects.

So.... if your `<Route />` doesn't have `:params` then the keys value will be an empty array and you will not have any params on `match`.

In conclusion, it looks like you're going to have to get the params yourself if your route isn't taking them into account. You could to that by using `let id = window.location.pathname.split("/").pop()`.