# How to set typescript type for matchPath return value

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to use `matchPath` to extract a route param from the parent container as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/45492498/3574819

```
const topicMatch = matchPath(history.location.pathname, { path: '/:topic' });
```

When I `console.log(topicMatch.params)`, the object has the `topic` key set but if I try to access `topicMatch.params.topic` I get the following error:

> error TS2339: Property 'topic' does not exist on type '{}'.

```
const RouterApp = withRouter<{}>(
    class App extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<{}>, AuthState> {
        render() {
            const { history } = this.props;    
            const topicMatch = matchPath(history.location.pathname, { path: '/:topic' });

            if (topicMatch) {
                console.log(topicMatch.params); // has topic key
                console.log(topicMatch.params.topic); // causes compile error
            }

            return (
                <div className="App">
                    <div className="App-header">
                        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo"/>
                        <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`matchPath` is a parameterized function that takes a generic type `<P>` and returns a match with `match<P>`. It's up to you to define `P`; otherwise I'm actually not sure how TypeScript determines the return type.

```
matchPath<{topic: "string"}>(...)
```

You could also create your own type if you wish, e.g.

```
interface RouteParams {
  topic: string;
}
```

and then do `matchPath<RouteParams>(...)`.