# Match type for react-router-dom in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a function that checks if the `currentUrl` matches a specific string:

```
  const checkingPage= (currentUrl: string): match<{}> | null => {
    const match = matchPath(currentUrl, {
      path: '/options/:optionId',
      exact: true,
      strict: false
    })

    return match
  }
```

I am not sure how to specify the type of the return`match`.

Currently I am getting the error:

> 'match' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here.ts(2749)

However, If I hover on `const match = matchPath(currentUrl...` it tells me the type is `match<{}> | null`

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set typescript type for matchPath return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47272473/how-to-set-typescript-type-for-matchpath-return-value)

Comment: I am not sure how to define the return type in a function that returns a `match`. If I do `const checkingPage= (currentUrl: string): matchPath<RouteParams>`  it still complains saying that `matchPath<RouteParams> refers to a value, but is being used as a type here`

Answer (score 4):

Typescript is getting confused because the same name `match` refers to both the local `match` variable in your function and the `match<T>` interface imported from "react-router-dom".  Usually interfaces and types use PascalCase and I'm not sure why this package doesn't.

If you are using the `match<T>` as your return type, then you need to include it in your import.

```
import {match, matchPath} from "react-router-dom"
```

Normally if you forgot to include an import, you would get the error `Cannot find name 'match'`.  But typescript did find the name `match` -- it found it as the name of your local variable, and that's why the error you get is telling you that you cannot use that variable as your return type.

Just import the interface and all is good.  If you're as annoyed by the lowercase name as I am, you can also rename it when importing.

```
import {matchPath, match as Match} from "react-router-dom"
```